Can someone tell me what is the time complexity of this code?
Leetcode question :
Write a function to find the longest common prefix string amongst an array of strings.
If there is no common prefix, return an empty string "".
Example 1:
Input: strs = ["flower","flow","flight"]
Output: "fl"
class Solution {
    public String longestCommonPrefix(String[] strs) {
    if(strs==null || strs.length ==0){
        return "";
    }
 
    if(strs.length == 1){
        return strs[0];
    }
 
    int i=0;
    while(true){
        boolean flag = true;
        for(int j=1; j<strs.length; j++){
            if(strs[j].length()<=i || strs[j-1].length() <=i 
               || strs[j].charAt(i) != strs[j-1].charAt(i)){
                flag = false;
                break;
            }               
        }
 
        if(flag){
            i++;
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
 
    return strs[0].substring(0, i);
  }
} ```


I haven't checked the correctness of your algorithm but the worst case here is when all strings are equal and since this is a nested loop it would boil down to O(n * m), where n = strs[0].length and m = strs.length.
The outer loop goes over each char position, and the inner loop goes over each string in the array. In the worst case, flag is never set to false, so it runs the whole thing.

Please correct that typo, m is strs.length.
